# Angular, Converting JSON , Rxjs Opertaor, Typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, operators

I received the following object (**Survay**)  JSON format  from server

/**************************************/

```
    {
        "id": 870,
        "title": "test survay ",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 871,
               
                "data": "question data 1"
               
            },
            {
                "id": 874,
                "data": "question data 2"
              
            },
            {
                "id": 877,
                "data": "question data 3"
                
            }
           
        ],
        "user": {
            "id": 788,
            "name": "mohamed",
            "answres": [
              
              {
                "data":"answere question 1"
              
              },
              {
                "data":"answere question 2"
              
              },
              {
                "data":"answere question 3"
              
              }
              
              ]
           
    
        }
 
   }
```

I used the following code

```
getSurvayByid(id: number) {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': this.loadToken(),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });
            return this.http.get<Survay>(this.host + "/survay/" + id, { headers: headers })
                .pipe(map(resp => resp));
    
        }
```

I would like to change this format as it’s displayed:

My question:how I can get this format using the Rxjs operators ?
(map, take, pipe...) and change the method   **getSurvayByid(id: number)**

```
 {
        "id": 870,
        "title": "test survay ",
        "questions": [
            {
                "id": 871,
               
                "data": "question data 1",
                "answer":"answere question 1"
               
            },
            {
                "id": 874,
                "data": "question data 2",
                 "answer":"answere question 2"
              
            },
            {
                "id": 877,
                "data": "question data 3",
                 "answer":"answere question 3"
                
            }
           
        ],
        "user": {
            "id": 788,
            "name": "mohamed"
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getSurvayByid(id).toPromise().then(s => {


            s.questions.forEach((q,i)=>{this.answers=s.user.answres!
                if(this.answers.length==0){
                    q.answer="";
                }


          else {
                q.answer=this.answers[i].data;
            }
           
            
            })
          
           
        }
```

Comment: While this solution works, I'll suggest to fix type errors by properly using typescript rather than using toPromise. With this solution you cannot use RxJS operators.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the answers are in correct order, you can do it like this:

```
    return this.http.get<Survay>(this.host + "/survay/" + id, { headers: headers }).pipe(
       map((resp: Survay): Survay => {
          resp.questions.forEach((question, i) => question.answer = resp.answers.length == 0 ? '' : resp.answers[i].data);
          return resp;
       })
    );
```

I'm assuming the return type is also `Survay`. Please replace with correct return type.

Comment: thank you for that answer but  the type of return  getSurvayByid(id: number )  it  change  from Observable<survay> a Observable<void>  so to correct this  trouble  apply the forEach inside   toPromise().then  or subscribe()   see the answer this below

Comment: You should fix such type issues by properly using typescript rather than converting to Promises. RxJS is very powerful and using toPromise cripples it's potential. I'll update my answer with proper types.